# Getting friendlist from facebook in android app using lates sdk

Tags: android, android-facebook

I am trying build a app which post message on the facebook wall of friend.And i want to get list of friends and want to pick friend and send message to my friend.But i cannot get list of friends using facebook sdk.i can list size zero.Can anyone help me?I have posted my code here.

```
public void btnFacebookClicked(View view) {


openActiveSession(this,true,statusCallback);
}

    Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new Session.StatusCallback()
    {
        @Override
        public void call(final Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception)
        {
            if(session.isOpened())
            {


                requestFacebookFriends(session);


            }
        }
    };
 private void requestFacebookFriends(Session session) {
        Request.executeMyFriendsRequestAsync(session,
                new Request.GraphUserListCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(List<GraphUser> users,
                                            Response response) {
                        // TODO: your code for friends here!
 Log.e("THIS IS FRIENDLIST",users.size()+"");
                    }
                });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using the facebook Graph v2.0,  as of 30.4.2014 you cannot retrieve a full list of friends from facebook, only the ones who are using the app.

Comment: yes,i found about it just yesterday.Thanks for the information.